# GAE Datastore Text messes up JSON representation

Tags: java, json, text, google-cloud-datastore, gson

The following code excerpt builds a Google App Engine Datastore Entity from a Java Map. Short strings (less than 450 characters) are stored directly, long strings are converted to Text objects.

```
for (String key : movieMap.keySet()) {
    String value = movieMap.get(key).trim();
    if (value.length()>0 && value.length()<450) {  // Short String - store as is
        movieEntity.setProperty(key, value);
    } else if (value.length()>=450) {              // Long String - convert to text
        movieEntity.setProperty(key, new Text(value));
    }
}
```

The following code retrieves the Entity as a Json object:

```
Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
result.put("numberOfMovies", String.valueOf(movies.size()));
result.put("movies", movies);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
resp.getWriter().print(gson.toJson(result));
```

The result JSON for a String `description` fields:

```
{

      "propertyMap": {
        "title": "טאנו מתחתנת עם מאנו - Tanu Weds Manu",
        "duration": "154 דקות",
        "movieId": "2315",
        "image_url": "http://www.sderot-cin.org.il/media/sal/movies2009/2315/f18_tano mithatenet iim mano.jpg",
        "description": "סינמסטה - מועדון הסרט ההודי רופא ממוצא הודי חוזר מלונדון במטרה לפגוש את כלתו המיועדת. הוא מופתע לגלות כי היא מאוהבת במישהו אחר ואין בכוונתה להינשא לו. התנהגותה הפראית גורמת לו לשקול מחדש את צעדיו.",
        "explorationDate": "Apr 26, 2013 8:42:36 PM",
        "actors": "קנגנה רנאוט, אר מדווהין",
        "year": "2011",
        "language": "הינדית",
        "director": "אנאנד ראי",
        "country": "הודו"
      }
    },
    {
```

The result JSON for a Text `description` fields, with a strange inner dictionary:

```
      "propertyMap": {
        "title": "הנעליים של אדון סימון - הצגת תיאטרון לילדים",
        "movieId": "2316",
        "image_url": "http://www.sderot-cin.org.il/media/sal/movies2009/2316/f18_anaaliim shel adon simon.jpg",
        "description": {
          "value": {
            "value": "תיאטרון אורנה פורת לגילאי 3-7 אדון סימון עוזב את ארצו ועובר לגור בארץ אחרת. בביתו החדש הוא מחליט להיפרד מנעליו הישנות שליוו אותו כל חייו ולהחליפן בנעליים חדשות, אך משום מה הוא לא מצליח להיפטר מהישנות. בכל פעם שהוא זורק אותן, רחוק ככל שיהיה, הן תמיד חוזרות אליו בדרך פלא. הצגה מרגשת ומצחיקה שמלמדת אותנו לקבל בשמחה את הדברים החדשים שבחיינו ובאותו זמן להבין שאפשר גם להתגעגע לדברים הישנים. משך ההצגה כ50 דקות.  כרטיסים: מכירה מוקדמת-30 ₪, ביום ההצגה-40 ₪ מנוי/מלווה : מכירה מוקדמת 20 ₪, ביום ההצגה  30 ₪."
          }
        },
        "explorationDate": "Apr 26, 2013 8:42:36 PM"
      }
    },
```

The problem is that the `description` field returns normaly (`key`:`value` pair) for String field, but has a strange inner `value` key for Text fields - compare `description` in both examples.

Any idea how can I make `Text` fields behave normally and appear as the standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the inner dictionary is a result of serializing the complex GAE Datastore Text object.

Since you're accessing your fields of your data with keys then I guess annotations and some getter/setter methods isn't possible?

In such case a simple way to fix it may be to iterate through the Map after it is retrieved and set (replace) the Text "description" fields with standard String if they were of type Text.

Then when you serialize to JSON those strings will be handled as the other strings.